# Updating the connector creation in diagram link table

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have created the connectors through ad-din and the connectors will be auto updated in the diagram.But the problem is when we try to find the connector in the diagram link table the connector will not be updated.So how can we parallel y create the connectors and add the line style to the connector diagram link.

Connectors are created using the below API

```
EA.Connector con = pPortsource.Connectors.AddNew("", "Association");
con.SupplierID = Porttarget.ElementID;
con.Update();
```

using this above API whether the diagram link in the diagram is automatically created or should we use the below code to create the diagram link

```
  EA.DiagramLink link=Diagram.AddNew("","");
  link.ConnectorID=con.ConnectorID;
  Link.update();
```

Comment: You mean the Element/Relationships window?

Comment: relationship window

Comment: Could you please answer with a sentence?

Comment: We have created the connector using Addnew Api. Once the connector is created  then connectors are visible in the diagram which are diagram links but why it is not getting updated in t_daiagramlink table. For this should we create diagramlink using Addnew API

Comment: If the connector source object and destination object is available in any diagram , under that diagram the diagram links will be available .

Comment: I had asked about the window you said it's not refreshed. Which is this window?

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: Hmm. Your last code is simply rubbish. You don't create diagram links, since EA does that for you. Still you have not answered my question about the window you are referring. Is it the one I mentioned above?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the diagram or closing and reopening the project?

Comment: Actually the relationship windows and element windows is working fine.As soon as we create connector EA will handle the diagram links .In EA we have Database table "t_DiagarmLinks" which  has to be updated with all the connectors that are present.But through add-in if we create the Connector the t_diagramLink table has no rows created in it,but when we drop some element from toolbox the table t_DiagramLink will be updated with all connectors.So what can be the issue.The problem is I want to set the linestyle of connector through update query Since the table is empty this is not working

Comment: @MartinGrégoire Yes i tried refreshing the diagram but still the t_diagramlink table is not getting updated

Comment: @Manishkumar is right when we create the EA Connectors through add-in the t_diagramlink table will not be updated with connector styles.The table will be empty.So is there any way to reload the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having grasped what your basic issue is: setting a default line style. You would do that with `Tools > Options > Links > Default Style > Routing` and/or `Tools > Options > Links > Generalization link style Default = Tree`. This is what EA offers.

In case you want something else, you are more or less lost, except you put a lot of tricky effort in your add-ins. Why that? Consider you add a new connector. This will not only appear in the diagram you are currently working on, but also in all diagrams where the two connected elements appear. Here I started experimenting and can confirm the OP's issue:

If you create a new connector without a diagram visible, EA will **not** create an entry in `t_diagramlinks`. It will then only create an entry if you modify the line style. A missing entry lets EA create a default connector style. Now, what you could do is to issue

```
Repository.Execute("INSERT INTO t_diagramlinks (diagramId, connectorId, style) VALUES (<diagramId>, <con.connectorID> 'Mode=2;')");
```

immediately after connector creation. This will set auto-routing for the connector in the single diagram. You can use a simple query to find all diagrams where the two connected elements are also present and repeat the above SQL accordingly. To make it complete you would also need to subscribe to `EA_OnPostNewDiagramObject` since that might also be the cause of the connector to appear on a diagram. I haven't tested this and whether EA will immediately create an entry in `t_diagramobject` so you could tweak that and whether you would need to reload the diagram to make the change visible. In any case, lots of tweaking ahead and it might spoil the already questionable EA user interface.

**Original answer**

In order to create new connectors and have them displayed you would use this (sorry for the Perl) code:

```
my $e = $rep->GetElementByGuid("{EB86E518-5BDC-477b-8CF8-2BEE0A102CF7}");
my $e1 = $rep->GetElementByGuid("{28636F81-2B1E-40af-A777-81ECEB067F31}");
my $con = $e1->Connectors->AddNew("", "Dependency");
$con->{SupplierId} = $e->ElementId;
$con->Update();

my $dia = $rep->GetCurrentDiagram();
$rep->ReloadDiagram ($dia->DiagramID);
```

This will create a new link as desired and EA will show it after the diagram is reloaded. You don't have to fiddle will DiagramLinks. The are only needed if you want to tweak connectors. That is, to hide them or add bends and the like.

Comment: how can we set the connector line style while creating the connector itself. In the connector window we have main tab which has the property Style So how can we access that through API or in EA which table contains that tag value

Comment: @ManuV t_diagramLinks will be updated if the connector is displayed in the diagram .You dont want to do this EA.DiagramLink link=Diagram.AddNew("",""); If connector objects is visible in any diagram , under that diagramlinks the added connector will be displayed

Comment: Through API I am able to get the DigarmLinks for the connectors but if i go to EA and in the SQL scratch pad if i try to view the t_diagramlink table it's showing empty